# Find longest path in directed acyclic graph

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics, directed-acyclic-graphs

Find a longest path between two nodes in an edge-weighted DAG.

Input: An edge-weighted graph, a source node source, and a sink node sink.

Output: The length of the longest path from source to sink, followed by a longest path.

```
Input:
0
4
0->1:7
0->2:4
2->3:2
1->4:1
3->4:3

Output:
9
0->2->3->4
```

The current solution passes for most test cases but there is an edge case that's not being accounted for **(input is not available).**

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict


def topological_sort(graph):
    indegree = {node: 0 for node in graph}
    for node in graph:
        for neighbor, _ in graph[node]:
            indegree[neighbor] += 1

    nodes_with_no_indegree = []
    for node in graph:
        if indegree[node] == 0:
            nodes_with_no_indegree.append(node)

    ordering = []
    while len(nodes_with_no_indegree) > 0:
        node = nodes_with_no_indegree.pop()
        ordering.append(node)
        for neighbor, _ in graph[node]:
            indegree[neighbor] -= 1
            if indegree[neighbor] == 0:
                nodes_with_no_indegree.append(neighbor)
    return ordering


def longest_path(source, sink, edges):
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for edge in edges:
        u, v, weight = edge.split(
            "->")[0], edge.split("->")[1].split(":")[0], edge.split("->")[1].split(":")[1]
        graph[u].append((v, -int(weight)))
    graph[str(sink)]
    ordering = topological_sort(graph)
    dist = {node: float('inf') for node in ordering}
    dist[str(source)] = 0

    pred = {}
    while len(ordering) > 0:
        u = ordering.pop(0)

        for v, weight in graph[u]:
            if dist[v] > dist[u] + weight:
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight
                pred[v] = u

    # Reconstruct the longest path
    longest_path = []
    u = str(sink)
    while u in pred:
        longest_path.append(u)
        u = pred[u]
    longest_path.append(str(source))
    longest_path.reverse()

    return -dist[str(sink)], '->'.join(longest_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    sink = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    edges = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]
    max_val, path = longest_path(source, sink, edges)
    print(max_val)
    print(path)
```

Comment: Can you provide me the link to the question you are solving on any portal?

Comment: @RohitSingh It is locked behind paid content as part of https://www.coursera.org/specializations/bioinformatics

Comment: Your code only works if every node in the graph is on a path from the source to the sink

Comment: @RohitSingh I've provided the correct solution below

Answer (score -1):

Fixed code:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def longest_path(source, sink, edges):
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for edge in edges:
        u, v_w = edge.split("->")
        v, w = v_w.split(":")
        graph[int(u)].append((int(v), int(w)))

    dist = {i: float('-inf') for i in range(sink+1)}
    dist[source] = 0
    path = {i: [] for i in range(sink+1)}

    for u in range(source, sink):
        for v, w in graph[u]:
            if dist[v] < dist[u] + w:
                dist[v] = dist[u] + w
                path[v] = path[u] + [u]

    longest_path = path[sink] + [sink]
    longest_path_str = "->".join(map(str, longest_path))
    return f"{dist[sink]}\n{longest_path_str}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    sink = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    edges = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]

    print(longest_path(source, sink, edges))
```